# Jscrollpane scroll issue on tablets

Tags: jquery, scroll, jscrollpane, tablet

I'm using Jscrollpane on a website to scroll 2 divs. One is a text area (links) and the other is a products area (images). While PC browsers have no problem with it, the issue is with an Ipad tablet. The links div still scrolls normally, but the images div while it does scroll the images remain fixed on the screen for a few seconds and then refresh to the other images.

This is how I load the script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('.side_menu').jScrollPane();
        $('.products_content').jScrollPane();
    });
});
```

I tried loading it also on window.load as the answer provided [here](http://offshootinc.com/blog/2010/03/02/jquery-jscrollpane-plugin-scrolling-divs-not-displaying-properly/). But is still not working.

**Edit:** I found an issue with the Vegas plugin. I just commented the script and the scroll started working. There might be some conflicts between the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use one DOM ready handler only:

```
$(function() {
    $('.side_menu').jScrollPane();
    $('.products_content').jScrollPane();
});
```

Comment: Still not working, but I did find an interesting issue. It seems to be conflicting with the Vegas plugin.